# how to create a not runnable/not executable jar with other external jar dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am unable to create normal jar (not runnable/not executable) through eclipse export wizard ,it only creates the jar file but the dependent jars are not exported resulting error while calling the methods of the exported jar from some other class , Please help

Comment: don't use eclipse for that kind of stuff, use a build tool like gradle, ant or maven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot @kurellajunior  for your suggestion .. it's solved by using the [zipgroupfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) .  **below is the ant script which perfectly creates the jar as I needed**

```
<project default="jar">
    <target name="jar">
            <jar destfile="destination directory/jarFileName.jar" basedir="my Eclipse project folder/bin (which holds all the .class files of my project separated by different package folder) ">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="Location of my external jar file directory" includes="*.jar"/>
            </jar>
        </target>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is intended in the language/IDE concept. You only create the jar (library).
Dependencies are managed outside (like in maven)
Executable jars can have a Manifest that points to the dependencies, but still the dependencies need to be bundled by you...

Netbeans in earlier time did a decent job in bundling all referenced jars together - haven't used it for a long time though.

Jan

EDIT:
There is an option to create such a jar - on commandline. As jar is just a zip container, you can easily write a script, that unjars all your dependencies together with your jar in one place and then jar it all again together.

**I do not recommend this!**